# about .htaccess, how can modify my domain?

Tags: .htaccess

about .htaccess, how can modify my domain?

this is my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

my domain is https://xxx.aaa.ccc/

but my folder address is https://xxx.aaa.ccc/blog/public/

how do I modify my htaccess when I type my domain https://xxx.aaa.ccc, can direct into my website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the immediate answer is: you need to implement a rewriting rule that "maps" the request root to that folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)$ /blog/public/$1 [END]
```

It would however be much easier to simply change your host configuration's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` entry to point there, if you have control over that.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: it's still not any function. my css link always is href="/css/main.css"
that'w way I need to change the default domain to https://xxx.xxx/blog/public
and my host company told me, they can't change the default folder /public_html.
Now my laravel folder put in /public_html/blog/public

Comment: You need to learn to keep separate things separate. "`https://xxx.xxx/blog/public`" is _not_ a "domain". It is a URL. Those are different things. And yes, the above code is not a "function"... Because request rewriting does not operate function based. I fail to understand your actual issue or why above rewriting rules should _not_ solve that issue. But it certainly is correct that you can not somehow magically change the http server's host configuration by means of an embedded distributed configuration file. That's not how things work, sorry.